# Why firefox gives outer element width based on actual image size and not the one from css?

Tags: html, css

How can I have fluid height stripe of images work correctly in firefox?

I noticed that in certain situation firefox gives actual width of image to the element containing it rather than width that is created by css. Chrome behaves normally.

I'm trying to put images on the stripe next to each other, and once the height of the container is fluid and not set in pixels this weird behaviour happens. So we have two images next to each other set via css to same width yet both give different width to their outer element. Below I put stripe with height that is not fluid but set in pixels and everything is back to normal. Please note this is not something that happens in Chrome.

```html
<div style="height: 20%; position: relative; white-space: nowrap">
  <div style="background: blue; display: inline-block; height: 100%">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="height: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div style="background: blue; display: inline-block; height: 100%">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" style="height: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 200px; position: relative; white-space: nowrap">
  <div style="background: blue; display: inline-block; height: 100%">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/" style="height: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div style="background: blue; display: inline-block; height: 100%">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" style="height: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Firefox gives width based on actual image width]

Answer (score -1):

Try this to solve your problem

```
<div style="height: 20%; position: relative; white-space: nowrap">
  <div style="background: blue; display: inline-block; height: 100%; float: left;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="height: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div style="background: blue; display: inline-block; height: 100%; float: left;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" style="height: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 200px; position: relative; white-space: nowrap">
  <div style="background: blue; display: inline-block; height: 100%">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/" style="height: 100%;">
  </div>
  <div style="background: blue; display: inline-block; height: 100%">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" style="height: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```